# Mocha async/await test is failing with timeout

Tags: javascript, async-await, automation, mocha.js, dockerode

I have a test where I am performing a docker stop operation and checking something and starting the docker container. I am using dockerode library. When I run that I test I keep getting the following error - **Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.**
I am using async/await. Here's the sample of the code

```
describe('docker container test', () => {
    let docker

    before(() => {
        docker = new Docker()
    })

    after( () => {
        docker = null
    })

it('simple docker test', async () => {
        try {
            container = await getDockerContainerByName(docker, containerName)
            await stopDocker(docker, container)
            await startDocker(docker, container)
            await waitForContainerToBeHealthy(docker, container)
            console.log("container healthy")
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("Error occurred "+ JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    }).timeout(120000)
})

async waitForContainerToBeHealthy (docker, container) {
        await invokeUntil(async (retry, complete) => {
            return dockerTestHelper.inspectDockerContainer(docker, container).then( (data) => {
                if(// check if container is healthy) {
                    complete()
                } else {
                    retry()
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

I can see on the console that the container is healthy. But, the test doesn't end. It hangs and after some time I see the error posted above. Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should throw an error after you print it

```
} catch(error) {
  console.log("Error occurred "+ JSON.stringify(error));
  throw error;
}
```

Now looking at your code, it actually looks good and should resolve, I would suggest you try to debug like this

```
it('simple docker test', (done) => {
  getDockerContainerByName(docker, containerName).then((container) => {
    console.log("reached 1");
    stopDocker(docker, container).then(() => 
    {
      console.log("reached 2");
      startDocker(docker, container).then(() => {
        console.log("reached 3");
        waitForContainerToBeHealthy(docker, container).then(() => {
          console.log("reached 4");
          done()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

If it reached the `done()` call, the test will be resolved.
so you should check if it reaches there **before the timeout is done**.
if you are absolutely sure it reached the `done()` on time, then you probably got a problem that is not shown in your post.

Comment: it is resolving but somehow test is not ending. It keeps running even after last function resolves.

Comment: if you implement what I added here, you will just need to figure out if it reached the `done()` method, if it did, the test will be resolved, if it didn't, you should debug why

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not return dockerTestHelper here
you don't use the variable
the approach you used to ditch the done is a really smart thing to do
but I think Mocha thinks that still you are returning a promise.
my suggestion is to change your code to this and see if it work or not

```
const data = await dockerTestHelper.inspectDockerContainer(docker, container);
if(// check if container is healthy) {
    complete()
  } else {
    retry()
}
```

I hope it help